# What causes compiler to warn for unused functions?

Tags: c, arrays, prototype, function-pointers, gcc-warning

Simple setup: There are n prototypes for functions and implementations of the functions. There is one big array of function pointers. Each function is listed in this array. Some still cause -Wunused-function when compiling with gcc.

Code:

```
void foo1(void);
void foo2(void);
void bar1(void);
void bar2(void);

/* and their implementations */

void (*functions[])(void) = { foo1, foo2, bar1, bar2 };
```

This is what the setup looks like (just an example)! One of this foo/bar functions now causes a -Wunused-function warning when compiling with gcc. Others don't. Why?

Comment: Can you post something that we can actually compile to get your warning ?

Comment: I can't convince my gcc (4.7.1) to emit a warning. What version did you use?

Comment: Well, the actual code is much more complex of course. It has some more errors and does not link at the moment, but if you want, you can compile it: http://beyermatthias.de/git/index.php?p=minx.git&a=shortlog&h=refs/heads/split_source My gcc version is 4.7.2

Comment: That's the first step in debugging it. Reproduce it in a minimal environment to narrow it down to the actual cause.

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that these lines are not the source of the warning. The warning is raised for static functions, and these functions are not static.

Comment: If `functions` is never referenced they may all be unused...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **-Wunused-function**
>
> Warn whenever a static function is declared but not defined or a non-inline static function is unused. This warning is enabled by **-Wall**.

This warning seems to trigger *both* when a function is never used *and* when a function is declared (prototyped) but not defined.

Are you sure you didn't miss implementing any of the functions you declared?

Comment: If you use a function without definition that way you'll get a linker error, not a compiler warning.

Comment: hmmh. Yes I'm sure and checked it. This is weird for me!

Comment: @cnicutar: Not if you don't actually call it.

Comment: @dranov I just tried it my gcc and it produced a linker error. here is ideone: http://ideone.com/mXOAab Like I said. If you use it that way you'll get an error.

Comment: @cnicutar: `void foo(void); int main(void) {return 0;}` compiles and links without problems on my computer with both gcc and clang.

Comment: @dranov I don't think you read my comments carefully enough. Simply having a declaration is ok. Using it the way the OP does is not.

Comment: @cnicutar: You're right. I misunderstood what you were saying. Of course you need an implementation if you want a function pointer (what else would you point to?)

Comment: I'll mark this as correct answer now. My problem was, that there were old "static" keywords, they shouldn't have been there, but they were. So it was my fault. Anyway, thank you all for answering, I learned something, so it wasn't useless!