# Unused function warning

Tags: c, xcode

I have method in header file to which I added `static` keyword. e.g.

```
static int32_t Tlvlist_AddRawt(Tlvlist *a, uint8_t type, uint16_t size, const void *bytes);
```

The method is implemented in .c file where the static
keyword is not present in function name.

This method is called from another function of same .c file.
The later function (which uses this static function) is also called from main.

But I get warning: "Unused function 'Tlvlist_AddRawt'" in the header file.
Why would this happen?

ps. I use Xcode.

Comment: Why did you add `static`?

Comment: @Kevin: why is it added usually? some access control

Comment: To do its job - prevent other files from being able to see or use the function.

Comment: If you add static to the declaration, then is the function only in the file with the declaration visible not in other files!

Comment: @Kevin: that is why I added it

Comment: Mayby this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14662561/3933332

Comment: You shouldn't put the static declaration in a header file where other files that import it can see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you mark a function declaration static, it is not visible outside the translation unit in which it appears.  But also, it represents a *different function* in every translation unit in which it appears.  As such, it is rarely a good idea to use `static` in a header file, because then you're declaring a separate function in each C source that includes the header.

The compiler diagnostic is telling you that there is at least one C file that includes your header but does not provide a definition of `Tlvlist_AddRawt()` to go with the declaration from the header.

If you want to declare a static function separately from its definition -- for instance to prototype it for other functions that appear earlier in the source file -- then put the declaration in at the top of the C source file in which its body appears instead of in a header.  Putting it in a header is counterproductive.

Answer (score 4):

You never declare `static` functions in a header file intended for use in other modules, because the purpose behind making a function `static` is "hiding" it from users outside your modules. Static C functions are visible only inside the translation unit<sup>*</sup> where they are defined. When a function is declared static, but no other functions from the same translation unit use it, you get the "unused static" warning.

If you would like to define a function in one file, and use it from another file, you need to put its forward declaration in a header, include that header from both translation units, and link the translation results together. Removing the `static` keyword from the header should address this problem.

<sup>*</sup> *Translation Unit* is a fancy name for a .c file.

Comment: @georgem Then there is no point to declare it `static` in the header. In fact, I have hard time coming up with a good use case for declaring a `static` function in a header at all: you put its forward declaration at the top of X.c file itself, along with `static` keyword, before the first use of the function. Remove it from the header, and compile.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: This might be useful, but only for the case of `inline static` (C99) forward declaration along with as such definition inside header (i.e. declaration is not really needed then). I guess it's the only exception, that makes at least some sense.